# Display the title of related nodes from taxonomy in block

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

How can I display the title of related news in a block shown in node page?

For example, I create the content type "news", and add "news" nodes that have taxonomy terms taken from the same vocabulary; now I want to show the list of the related node basing on the taxonomy terms associated with the nodes.

How can I display this bock only for "news" nodes?

Comment: Can you retag this with either drupal-6 or drupal-7? Thanks.

Comment: @tim.plunkett: The user doesn't have an account on drupal.SE.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to accomplish this.

To display a block that lists other node titles with related taxonomy terms:

1. Create a Block View
2. Add the field `Node:Title` (make it link to its node)
3. Add the argument `Taxonomy: Term ID`
4. Configure this argument as follows:

   > - Check `Provide default argument`
   > - Select `PHP Code`
   > - Add the following code:

   `$node = node_load(arg(1));

     if($node) {

       if ($node->taxonomy) {

         foreach($node->taxonomy as $term) { $terms[] = $term->tid; }

         return implode('+',$terms);

       }

       else {

         return;

       }

     }

     else {

         return;

     }`

   > - Check `Allow multiple terms per argument`
   > - Check `Reduce duplicates`
5. Now you need to add the second argument in order to exclude the current node from the list. Click [+] button of the arguments section.
6. Select `Node:Nid`
7. Set the "Action to take if argument is not present" to `Provide default argument`
8. Set the "Default argument type" to `Node ID from URL`
9. Check `Exclude the argument`
10. Save your view

You can customize this however you like, such as filtering to a specific content type (ie "News"), can filter by post date, sort by: post date, random, etc.

For a whole discussion on this see http://drupal.org/node/65375

(Sorry for the poor code formatting, not sure how to format code inside a blockquote and list)

Answer (score 2):

The [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) will help you with that. With it you can show blocks on selected node types, views etc.

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of related terms, Laxman's answer is the better way. To show this list only at content type news you can use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module as said in googletorp's answer.

Comment: You can make the block show only on certain content types with the Views approach as well.