# How can I create a custom field block to read from another field from the node?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a page created from views with several nodes. That page is created specifying which nids I want the view to load from. See [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39811/create-a-view-from-specific-node-ids) thread for details on that. Each node displayed on that page contains taxonomy terms. Each of those terms contain other nodes. Usually a small number like 2 or 3. So it kind of like this;

--------------------Main Page----------------

- [Node A:(nid=20)]

  - Field1: Title
  - Field2: Image
  - Field3: Term (Spoons)
  - Field4: Related Node Image Block (Supposed to read Term from Field3. Created in views)
- [Node B:(nid=30)]

  - Field1: Title
  - Field2: Image
  - Field3: Term (Knives)
  - Field4: Related Node Image Block (Supposed to read Term from Field3. Created in views)
- [Node C:(nid=40)]

  - Field1: Title
  - Field2: Image
  - Field3: Term (Forks)
  - Field4: Related Node Image Block (Supposed to read Term from Field3. Created in views)

-------------------End of Main Page--------------

I created a custom field: Block. I added the block to read from each term, and pull the image used in the other nodes that share the term and link to them. Basically, the same product just of a different color.

*-Things I've Tried-*

- Created a RELATIONSHIP filter; "Content: Taxonomy terms on node". Then created a contextual filter; "Taxonomy term: Term ID" to use that relationship. Didn't Work. (This is a method I used in ANOTHER view block created. But it works because the term is in the url. See next item. The page I created **DOES NOT** contain the term in the url.
- I've seen code for previous versions of drupal. http://drupal.org/node/76923. But, I believe that for D7. They have removed the taxonomy_node_get_terms(). **Looking to find a D7 Alternative to get the term from the nid of the current load.**
- Tried using [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/654/display-the-title-of-related-nodes-from-taxonomy-in-block) method but it didn't work either.

**How can I create a block to read from a field from the node its loaded in?** (See *Field4* in the example)